# VS C++ (or C?) DLL export: HWND data type with OpenClipboard?

Tags: c++, c, dll, hwnd

I have no knowledge of C or C++. I'm using visual studio and following a tutorial to create a DLL for use with another program. This is the entirety of the cpp file:

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) bool my_open_clipboard(HWND window)
{
    return OpenClipboard(window);
}
```

I think it is not accepting HWND as a data type? Is it interpreting HWND as an identifier instead of a data type? The error message confuses me. It says "Error C2065   'HWND': undeclared identifier" on line 4. I tried rewriting it with many variations but I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` must be the first non-comment line in a source file. When using precompiled headers (the default), everything above that line is ignored. The compiler should have issued a warning to that effect.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Why not write an answer so it can be accepted and this question can be considered answered?